# RPM installation on redhat 6.3 failed

Tags: linux, rpm

I am trying to install `unixODBC-2.2.14-11.el6.x86_64.rpm` on `redhat 6.3`. It gives me the following output:

```
[root@localhost khan]# yum install unixODBC-2.2.14-11.el6.x86_64.rpm


Loaded plugins: product-id, refresh-packagekit, security, subscription-manager
Updating certificate-based repositories.
Unable to read consumer identity
Repository InstallMedia is listed more than once in the configuration
Setting up Install Process
Examining unixODBC-2.2.14-11.el6.x86_64.rpm: unixODBC-2.2.14-11.el6.x86_64
unixODBC-2.2.14-11.el6.x86_64.rpm: does not update installed package.
Error: Nothing to do
```

But when I try to query it by `#rpm -q unixODBC-2.2.14-11.el6.x86_64.rpm`,

it gives the output as:

```
package unixODBC-2.2.14-11.el6.x86_64.rpm is not installed
```

Comment: `yum` is telling you that you already have this RPM installed, and there's nothing left for it to do. I don't see a problem here.

Comment: thanks for comment Sir, then why the rpm -q is telling that the package is not installed Mureinik

Comment: Oh, I see the problem now. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

You are misusing the `rpm` command. With the `-q` option, `rpm` receives a package name, not a file name. Drop the `.rpm` from the end, and you should be OK:

```
$ rpm -q unixODBC-2.2.14-11.el6.x86_64
```

Comment: The proper way is to not include the version because if the installed packages is not exactly the same version as your query, then it will return empty. `rpm -q unixODBC` should be enough to see if the exact version or newer is already installed. Or `rpm -q unixODBC.x86_64` if you need to be specific about the architecture.